# Can we self-host pd.js?

Tags: javascript, integration, pardot

We are adding the Pardot tracking script to some of our pages. Looking at the JS, all it does is set a couple of variables and load a further JS file (https://pi.pardot.com/pd.js). Is there any reason why we couldn't host the pd.js file ourselves?

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason why you couldn't include the script in your VF Page, it may not work as well with Lightning components so I would check for conflicts. Also various security protocols may cause issues including remote scripts in Lightning components.

You could include the JS file as a [static resource](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_resources.htm) which would make it static to your resource file, but you would have to make sure to update it with Pardot's API